# How can i fetch a value in this array (php)

Tags: php

i have a file with this array content (bottom) , how can i get a value ?

```
    Array
(
    [id_product] => 29438.199
    [mojoodi] => 29.000000
    [price] => 20000.0000
)
Array
(
    [id_product] => 25912.199
    [mojoodi] => 72.000000
    [price] => 215000.0000
)
Array
(
    [id_product] => 24617.199
    [mojoodi] => 22.000000
    [price] => 34900.0000
)
```

my code for put data in the file is :

```
$myfile = fopen("test.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
for($i =0;$i<=50;$i++) {

$data = array("id_product"=>"$product_ids[$i]", "mojoodi"=>"$mojoodi[$i]", "price"=>"$price[$i]");
$results = print_r($data, true);
fwrite($myfile, $results);

}
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: Which value do you need?

Comment: What is your array name?

Comment: You need to go through some beginner php tutorials.

Comment: You question requires editing

Comment: @Hassaan for example price of The second array

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @Shanukk look this $data = array("id_product"=>"$product_ids[$i]", "mojoodi"=>"$mojoodi[$i]", "price"=>"$price[$i]");

Comment: echo $data[1]['price'] try this

Comment: `print_r()` is meant for showing data to programmers, it's not for storing data in files if you want to read it back. You should use `json_encode()` or `serialize()`

Comment: @barmar worked Well , thanks !

Comment: Thanks @Hassaan too

Comment: @NimaEidipour I provide you solution first. You can consider my answer and mark tick on it. If it works for you.

Comment: @Hassaan both is well but lets try with your code

Comment: @NimaEidipour have you tried my solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `print_r()` if you need to parse the data. Use JSON or serialize.

```
$array = array();
for($i =0;$i<=50;$i++) {
    $array[] = array("id_product"=>"$product_ids[$i]", "mojoodi"=>"$mojoodi[$i]", "price"=>"$price[$i]");
}
file_put_contents("test.data", serialize($array));
```

Then when you want to read it back, you do:

```
$array = unserialize(file_get_contents("test.data"));
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all your are overwritting `$data` by assigning value again and again to change the following line

```
$data = array("id_product"=>"$product_ids[$i]", "mojoodi"=>"$mojoodi[$i]", "price"=>"$price[$i]");
```

into

```
$data[] = array("id_product"=>"$product_ids[$i]", "mojoodi"=>"$mojoodi[$i]", "price"=>"$price[$i]");
```

Then you can get 2nd array's price index via following code.

```
echo $data[1]['price'];
```